# Build Error: gradlew-fdroid no such file macOS

Tags: react-native, build, gradlew, fdroid

I’m trying to upload my react native application to F-droid.
fdroidserver was installed using brew.
When i try build app:

```
fdroid build free.vpn.unblock.proxy.opensource
```

This returns at the end:

```
ERROR: Could not build app free.vpn.unblock.proxy.opensource: OSError while trying to execute /usr/local/Cellar/fdroidserver/2.2.1/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gradlew-fdroid clean: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/Cellar/fdroidserver/2.2.1/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gradlew-fdroid'
```

My metadata file:

```
AntiFeatures:
  - NonFreeNet
  - Tracking
Categories:
  - Internet
  - Security
License: GPL-3.0-or-later
AuthorWebSite: https://vpn.llill.xyz/
SourceCode: https://github.com/b4a0/VPN_ReactNative

AutoName: Open Source VPN

RepoType: git
Repo: https://github.com/b4a0/VPN_ReactNative

Builds:
  - versionName: '1.2'
    versionCode: 3
    commit: 79eb7d6
    subdir: android/app
    sudo:
      - sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
      - curl -Lo node.tar.xz https://nodejs.org/dist/v16.14.0/node-v16.14.0-linux-x64.tar.xz
      - echo "0570b9354959f651b814e56a4ce98d4a067bf2385b9a0e6be075739bc65b0fae node.tar.xz"
        | sha256sum -c -
      - tar xJf node.tar.xz
      - cp -a node-v16.14.0-linux-x64/. /usr/local/
    init: npm install
    gradle:
      - yes
    scanignore:
      - android/build.gradle
      - android/app/build.gradle
      - node_modules/hermes-engine
      - node_modules/jsc-android
      - node_modules/react-native/android/com/facebook/react/react-native/*/
      - node_modules/react-native-device-info/android/build.gradle
      - node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context/android/build.gradle
      - node_modules/react-native-screens/android/build.gradle
      - node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android/build.gradle
      - node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/build.gradle
    scandelete:
      - node_modules/
    ndk: r21e

MaintainerNotes: scanignore is used to allow the "node_modules/react-native/android"
    local Maven repository.

AutoUpdateMode: Version
UpdateCheckMode: Tags
CurrentVersion: '1.2'
CurrentVersionCode: 3
```

The main problem is that when installing fdroidserver on macos, the gradlew-fdroid file is not added.
Some help? Thank you.